# Twilio Fax-to-email

Tags: twilio

Has anyone configured a fax-to-email setup on Twilio? If so, your help is much appreciated.

We have already tried contacting Twilio support but their turnaround time has been less than favourable as it has taken almost a month now to get a follow-up.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not an appropriate place for this type of question. I do not think you will find an appropriate discussion place within the StackExchange environment for Twillo support.

Comment: Please see my answer here to do this with Google apps script
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426243/how-do-i-retrieve-the-twilio-fax-pdf-and-attach-it-to-an-email-using-node-js-ins/62945989#62945989

Answer (score 3):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here. Check out https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/12/fax-to-email-twilio-functions-sparkpost.html, which walks through setting that up!

Comment: this is a way to email incoming faxes is there a way to do it the other way email -> something -> twilio ?

Comment: Yes there is, at the bottom of the link above you'll find a link to https://www.sparkpost.com/blog/send-faxes-via-email/